# How to merge two rows into one in linq query in c#

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a sql table:

| Id | SENDER | USERD_ID | BODY | TITLE | THREAD_ID | REPLIED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 15 | sth | some title | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | 2 | 16 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 3 | 2 | 17 | NULL | some title | NULL | NULL |
| 4 | 1 | 15 | sth1 | question | 501 | 1 |
| 5 | 3 | 15 | sth2 | answer: question | 501 | NULL |
| 6 | 2 | 15 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

I would like to return a list with data looks like this:

```
[{id: 1, user_id: 15, body: "sth", title: "some title", threadMessage: null},
{id: 4, user_id: 15, body: "sth1", title: "question", 
threadMessage: {messageId: 5,threadId: 501, body: "sth2", title: "answer: question"}},
{id: 6, user_id: 15, body: null, title: "null", threadMessage: null}]
```

I have a quey like this:

```
var query = (from m in db.Message
                where m.USERD_ID = 15
                select new MessageTemp
                {
                 Id = m.Id,
                 Body = m.Body,
                 Title = m.Title
                })AsQueryable();
```

And I have no idea how to rewrite the condition in this query in the way it is possible to take information about messageThread for the same Thread_ID. And of course I need 3 items not 4.

Comment: The json is not valid.

Comment: To be honest it doesn't matter. I just would like to have a list with 3 items and to have an information about MessageThread for replied message wih the same ThreadId.

Comment: You asking about merge, but desired output doesn't looks like a merge, it looks like filtering (due to only `where`). And, if `db.Message` type isn't `MessageTemp` then it also looks like mapping. So what's your trouble?

Comment: You lost ID 5.  Use a GroupBy to merge rows by Sender.

Comment: I would like to have all messages for exact USERD_ID, but when I have two messages with the same ThreadId, I would like to merge this two messages into one with MessageThraed information.

Comment: Merge two into one - which criteria for merging? E.g. Id's 4 and 5, how you see merged `Body`? `"sth1sth2"`? Merged `Title` - `"questionanswer: question"`? You want between Id 4 and 5 take 5th, but by which criteria?)

Comment: @djweng I didn't miss ID 5. Group By Sender it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: What happened to rows 2 and 3? What is the exact desired logic to "merge"?

Comment: @Auditive so, I'm looking for if there is a message with REPLIED = 1 (which means, it is an answer for this message),  and if there is a message with REPLIED = 1 I check ThreadId and I'm looking for the second message with the same ThreadId.

Comment: @Charlieface ok, I'm looking for all messages for exact USERD_ID and then when there is a message with REPLIED = 1 I check THREAD_ID and then I'm looking for a second message with the same THREAD_ID (and these two I want to merge in a way I showed).

Comment: What if you have multiple replies? And how do you know whether a row is the first in the thread?

Comment: @Charlieface there is possible only one replied, and first should be a message with replied  = 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use a subquery

```cs
var query = (
    from m in db.Message
    where m.USERD_ID == 15
       && (m.THREAD_ID == null || m.Replied == 1)
    select new MessageTemp
    {
        Id = m.Id,
        UserId = m.USERD_ID,
        ThreadId = m.THREAD_ID,
        Body = m.Body,
        Title = m.Title,
        ThreadMessage =
          m.Replied == 1
          ? (
            from m2 in db.Message
            where m2.THREAD_ID == m.THREAD_ID
               && m2.Id != m.Id
            select new MessageTemp
            {
                Id = m.Id,
                UserId = m.USERD_ID,
                ThreadId = m.THREAD_ID,
                Body = m.Body,
                Title = m.Title,
            }
          ).FirstOrDefault()
          : null,
    }).AsQueryable();
```